# How to get push notifications from Twitter RSS Feeds in Android 2.1?

Tags: java, android, twitter

Just wonder whether it's possible to get real-time notifications from a twitter account in Android

Twitter feeds can be accessed from here.
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=xx

But I do not like to use a background task to query feeds always. Is there a better way to do this? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RSS? Not possible. They don't generate push notifications.